# java processing input from command line

Tags: java, command-line, input

I was trying to implement a `java` program to process user input from command line.The problem was one given in `Algorithms` book (`sedgewick`)

> 1.1.21 Write a program that reads in lines from standard input with each line contain- ing a name and two integers and then uses printf()
>   to print a table with a column of the names, the integers, and the
>   result of dividing the first by the second, accurate to three decimal
>   places. You could use a program like this to tabulate batting averages
>   for baseball players or grades for students.

I tried to implement this as follows..but I am stuck in storing the user input sothat it can be printed using `printf()` ..I thought Scanner would be  appropriate for getting the user input..Still I can't seem to get the input stored for later use.

The class `Stack` is from sedgewick's book.

Any idea how to get this right?

```
 Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);        
    Stack st = new Stack();
    while(input.hasNext()){
        String tkn =  input.next();
        st.push(tkn);           
        if (st.size()==3){
            int y = Integer.parseInt((String)st.pop());
            int x = Integer.parseInt((String)st.pop());
            String name = (String)st.pop();
            System.out.println("name="+name+",x="+x+",y="+y);

        }
    }
```

Comment: can you post an example of the line you are entering?

Comment: damon 1 2\n jon 2 3\n jim5 6\n and Ctrl-D to terminate input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the [st.pop()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html#pop%28%29) it will remove and return the last item of the stack. If you dont want it to get removed you can use one ordered `Collection` like [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) and access the item by [list.get](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#get%28int%29) or using an [Iterator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/AbstractList.html#iterator%28%29).

Another suggestion is to create one object to store the name and the y, x properties:

```
class MyObject {
    private String name;
    private int x;
    private int y;

   //... setter and getter methods for the properties
}
```

Suggestion for your code: it pushes the input in the `Stack`, then pop the items to create the `MyObject` and add to the `list`:

```
ArrayList listObjects = new ArrayList();
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);        
Stack st = new Stack();
while(input.hasNext()){
    String tkn =  input.next();
    st.push(tkn);           
    if (st.size()==3){
         int y = Integer.parseInt((String)st.pop());
         int x = Integer.parseInt((String)st.pop());
         String name = (String)st.pop();
         //create and add the object to the list for further use
         listObjects.add(new MyObject(name, x, y));
         System.out.println("name="+name+",x="+x+",y="+y);

     }
 }
```